# Live cd booting to initramfs : medium problem?

Tags: 12.04, live-cd

I am trying to boot a 12.04, 32 bit french version of the live cd, however it drops me
to an initramfs prompt.

If I look at the dmesg output, I have some cdrom I/O error (sr0 device).

If I check the md5sums, they are all good, except for a file :  ./isolinux/16x16.fnt

Should I retry burning a CD ?

Answer (score 1):

> *If I look at the dmesg output, I have some cdrom I/O error (sr0 device).
>
>   If I check the md5sums, they are all good, except for a file : ./isolinux/16x16.fnt*

This is most probably a burning/medium problem, and somewhat likely a hardware/drive problem. The `16x16.fnt` file being incorrect can be a problem (it's one of the boot menu graphical fonts).

I would re-burn, verify, and then try again; if you still get `/dev/sr0` errors, it may be time to try a different drive (or go Live-USB).

Comment: I burned a second CD that shows the same problem.

Comment: I think the problem may then be your drive. Can you try a Live-USB?

Comment: live USB worked fine (but I used the english version, not the fr localised one, it should not make a difference though)